# Audio - how to check if path is valid

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to play an audio file:

```
path = '/public/recordings/weekday/1.mp3'
const audio = new Audio(path)
audio.play()
```

If the path is NOT valid then the following warning appears in the console:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.`

is there a javascript method to check if the file exists so I can avoid calling play on it?

I imagine the answer could be in this doc:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType

I did find a workaround but I do NOT like it:

```
audio.addEventListener('error', function (err) {
   if (err.path[0].error.message.includes('DEMUXER_ERROR_COULD_NOT_OPEN')) {
      this.handleError()
    } else {
      this.handleSomeOtherError()
    }
}.bind(this), false)
```

Comment: Wrap it in a `try { } catch (e) { }`? I say this because even if a file exists, there is no guarantee that `Audio` can decode it.

Comment: I've tried that but it calls a global exception - it doesn't fall into the local catch phrase

Comment: Any idea how I could capture such an exception?

Comment: Are your audio files large? if not. `const audio = new Audio(path); audio.onload = () => audio.play()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw it in a promise.

```js
function Function() {
path = 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3';
var audio = new Audio(path);
var playPromise = audio.play();
if (playPromise !== undefined) {
  playPromise.then(_ => {
    audio.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
    document.body.appendChild(audio);
    audio.play();
  })
  }
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="Function()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a promise helped:

```
const playPromise = this.audio.play();
if (playPromise !== undefined) {
    playPromise.then(function() {
      console.log('Automatic playback started!!')
    }).catch(function(error) {
       console.log(error)
       this.handleError()
    }.bind(this), false);
 }
```